# Btrfs fsck running on boot every time?

Tags: fsck, btrfs

I've read some stuff that says that Btrfs fsck is run every time on bootup. Is this still true? If so how can you tell when it runs or does not run on bootup? I just installed Ubuntu Raring Ringtail with Btrfs.

Comment: Never heard of such a thing. Why should it do that?

Comment: Not sure what you are reading, but if a fsck is run, you'll know it.

Comment: [Btrfs FAQ](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What.27s_the_difference_between_btrfsck_and_fsck.btrfs): "Traditional filesystems need to run their respective fsck utility in case the filesystem was not unmounted cleanly and the log needs to be replayed before mount. This is not needed for btrfs. You should set fs_passno to 0. //
Note, if the fsck.btrfs utility is in fact btrfsck, then the filesystem is unnecessarily checked upon every boot and slows down the whole operation. It is safe to and recommended to turn fsck.btrfs into a no-op, eg. by cp /bin/true /sbin/fsck.btrfs."